# AD powershell validation

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script such that it does the following:

- IP address configured (for historical reasons, we have static IP
  addresses)
- Change hostname
- Choose OU
- Join domain
- Add user to remote desktop user

I have managed to code 4 of the above except I cannot get validating credentials to join the domain.  The problem I have is that it doesn't handle errors properly.  So it accepts empty password and jpoins the domain.

```
    $correct = $false
do{
$dompassword = Read-Host "Enter the domain administrator password for the host to join the mydomain domain" -AsSecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("mydomain\administrator", $dompassword)


try{
Write-Host "Adding $computername to the domain"
Add-Computer -DomainName "mydomain" -Credential $credentials -OUPath $ou
Rename-Computer -NewName $computername -DomainCredential $credentials -Force
$correct = $true
}
catch{
Write-Host "Password incorrect, please re-enter"
$correct = $false
}
```

How do I error handle the following:

- wrong password
- empty password

Comment: You should use Get-Credential instead

Comment: I tried the same, makes no difference.  It accepts anything.  Doesn't error handle it.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Test-Credential 1.4](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-Credential/1.4). More info: [Confirming/Validating PowerShell Get-Credential Input Before Use](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dsheehan/2018/06/23/confirmingvalidating-powershell-get-credential-input-before-use/)

Comment: Tried this one, but when I enter correct credentials it shows false.